# Combining/Merging two SimBIology Models

Tags: matlab

I am making two separate SimBiology Models with the same compartments but different species. Transport between the compartments are different for each species. I want to combine the two models so I can add an interaction term between the two species and use the simulations to get concentration profiles of both the species. Is there a function to do that in SimBiology? I have not been able to find one. If not, what would be the best approach to code a function to do so?

Answer (score 2):

The most relevant function is [copyobj](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simbio/ref/copyobj.html). You can also use the SimBiology Desktop's graphical interface to copy and paste one model into another. I also have a prototype of a function for combining two models that I would be happy to share. If you're interested in that, please contact me via my MathWorks [community profile](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/profile/authors/1520503-arthur-goldsipe).

Comment: does this mean we have to manually copy every single object from one model to another? I am pretty sure I have tried to copy an paste one model to another and it doesn't work. I think the graphical interface only allows a user to copy and paste the objects but not the whole model?

Comment: If you use copyobj, you will not need to copy every object one by one. For example, when you copy a compartment it copies all species in that compartment. My prototype function just does all the necessary copyobj operations.

I also just confirmed that I can use the graphical interface to copy an entire model. I just clicked on the diagram, selected everything, copied, and pasted in to a new model diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to write a script based on [copyobj](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html) function provided by Matlab, if you want to copy programmatically. You need to be little cautious here as this function throws an error, **IF** the object copied and the target model have name conflicts. For example, if you want to copy a compartment by name 'C1' from a source model to a target model that already contains a compartment by the same name ('C1'), then the program throws an error due to name conflicts. In such a case you have to programmatically rename the source 'C1' compartment before you copy it to the target model. The [rename](https://in.mathworks.com/help/simbio/ref/rename.html) command provided by Matlab might be useful.

Even after overcoming the errors due to name conflicts, there is another problem with the above method --- the layout/diagram of the models will not be preserved. If you want to preserve the model layout (that is the diagram of the model), you can use GUI based simbiology model builder. First you manually select the model/submodel that you want to copy, click 'Ctrl+C' (like you would do for copying a text) and paste (Ctrl+V) it in your target model. The name conflicts will be automatically handled by the matlab. That is the source 'C1' compartment will be automatically renamed by matlab (to probably 'C2'), and pasted in the target model.

You may look at [this function](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/116900-simbiology-model-merger), that probably helps you to build your custom model merger programmatically. It is an old function that works with older versions of Matlab, and may not be relevant now. But it may provide some guidance on building your own script.